# Undo SQL Server delete statement on simple recovery mode

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Current situation:

1. Delete command executed on production database SQL Server
2. Rows are not available in last backup
3. Recovery mode: simple
4. According to windows, the log file was last modified a day ago. Which if true raises the question: where are the transactions of today if they are not yet written to the log files. Are they still in the buffer??

Question:

1. Is there a possible way to recover the deleted data?
2. Is there a way to read what's in the buffer?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The last modified time shown in Windows Explorer only relates to the last time the file grew or shrank not the last time it was written to. [See this related question](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/7086/recover-accidentally-deleted-rows-from-a-table)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. No
2. No

You may attempt to recover the data using a 3rd party log file reader but it probably won't work.

The choice of "Simple" recovery defines your RPO as "last full backup".